# Jenkins - Sharing worskpace with parent job considering slaves, remote workspace

Tags: svn, jenkins, repository

I'm struggling with a Jenkins problem. It was even hard to describe it in the title, so sorry if you were confused.

My whole project structure is as follows:

main job:

- Checkout job into main job's directory
- Parametrized building job #1 ( using remote worspace [in this case it's the parent's folder])
- Parametrized building job #2 (same)
- Parametrized building job #X (same)

The problem is each building job executes a .bat file that is in a specific folder of the checked out SVN directory. In order to reuse code I am sticking to the job performed by bat files. Each of them takes parameters. One of the params is always a local directory on the slave.

I cannot accomplish my task because :
1) If I tried to use the %workspace% it doesn't work for custom workspace (it provides just the **RELATIVE**  path from the jenkins's folder. I can't afford to hardcode the path. Jenkins will be run on differents OSs.

2)  Using %JENKINS_HOME% + local redirecting fails as it provides the location of the jenkins on master (it's even a different OS)

3) Using %~dp0 for the bat (it's often use to receive the location where the files is executed) returns C:\Windows\Temp . I don't even have the strengh to inquire why.

I have ran out of ideas. I have been struggling for about 1.5 weeks now.

There are a couple of ways to restructurize the whole project but it will be time consuming and my present work will occur fruitless.

Comment: in your jenkins job, do you have a windows bat file build step?  That would explain why %~dp0 is resolving to %TEMP%.   jenkins actually creates .bat files in %TEMP% and runs them.

Comment: Yes I do, I launch the bat file creating a new build step - "Windows batch" . However, the bat file already exists so why would Jenkins create them again?

Comment: it does't create them again... it makes a bat file in %TEMP% that literally is the text of your build step  - it makes a bat to call your bat.

Comment: Great that would explain the behaviour :) Shame it doesn't quite solve my problem.